# Sql query with time and date

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a part of my sql query, I am very unsure when I for example do a query from date 11.05.2014 to 15.05.2014 with the time from 11.00.00 to 21.00.00.

The problem is that the results of for example 12.05.2014 23.00.00 won't show because it is not between the time from and to. I understand that I can only then search on date without time, but I also want the time for more specific results. Is it a solution for this problem ?

This sql query is just a part of the larger sql query. Thanks.

```
WHERE routines.date between '".$fromDate."' AND '".$toDate."'

AND routines.time between '".$fromTime."' AND '".$toTime."'
```

To correct:

The problem with the sql query is that it will show records for 13.05.2014, 13.05.2014, etc. But the time for those will only be between 11.00.00 and 21.00.00, but 24 hours. I only want the sql query to search from Time and To time those specified days..

Comment: mysql or sql-server ? what is the data type of date and time in the DB ?

Comment: Namaste! it is SQL server. Data type for time is time(0) and date is date.

Comment: use specific DB tag to avoid confusion. removed mysql tag per comment.

Comment: Do you mean that you want records that are between 11.05.2014 11.00.00 and 15.05.2014 21.00.00?

Comment: Yes, but the time for example 12.05.2014 has to be 24 hours, the only criteria is that the records has to be from 11.00.00 from 11.05.2014 and 24 hours the next days to 15.05.2014 to 21.00.00

Comment: In that case, you need to combine the date and time into a single value.  Something like:  WHERE routines.date+routines.time BETWEEN .$fromDate.+.$fromTime AND .$ToDate.+.$ToTime.   It's hard to be more specific without knowing the type of the fields, and what language you're using to access SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know reason why you created two columns with date and time instead of one, but for this query you need to combine them. For example, you can create [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and create an index on it.

Also, you can try this solution, but it will not use indexes if you have them on  `routines.date` and `routines.time`:

```
WHERE CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8),routines.date,112)+
      ' '+CONVERT(varchar(8),routines.time,108) as datetime) BETWEEN '".$fromDateTime."' AND '".$toDateTime."'
```